# Checked property not working in my Angular html template

Tags: html, angular

When I implemented my html template, checked property of checkbox is not properly working.

My html file contains code like the following,

```
<div *ngIf="userPermissionObj" >
        <label for="pm">Permissions:</label>
        <div *ngFor="let pt of permissionType">
          <label>
            <input type="checkbox" 
                [value]="pt.id"  
                ng-checked="${userPermissionObj.sPermissionType} == ${pt.name} ? true : false"  />
            {{pt.name}} 
        </label>
</div>
```

How can I find out where I implemented in wrong way?

Comment: ng-checked dont exist in angular. Its part of the old angularJS. use `[checked]` instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In new Angular ng-checked does not exists. To acheive the same, use `[checked]`:

`<input  type="checkbox"  [checked]="'Your_condition_here' ? true : false" (change)="someMethod()"/>`

Answer (score 1):

Use `[checked]` instead of `ng-checked` (It is angularJS directive, not angular.io),

See example below,

```
   <input type="checkbox"
   [value]="pt.id" 
   [checked]="${userPermissionObj.sPermissionType} == ${pt.name} ? true : false" >
```